# Ebean not recognizing java.time.LocalDate in Play 2.3.7. Upgrade default ebean of play

Tags: playframework, ebean

Rather strange problem, I am trying to use java.time package for LocalDate in my app, but Ebean is not recognizing the LocalDate variable. However, with DateTime(joda), ebean seems to work as usual, wherein, it creates a column with timestamp in my postgres db table.

I found that Java8 feature integration in ebean 4.4.1 is still in the process:
https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/178

Is there anyway I can upgrade the default version of my ebean in Play without having any dependency issues? Or is there any workaround to my problem with time?

Thanks in advance! :)